# Wordpress template directory PHP code outside of echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I hope this is a silly simple thing. All I'm trying to do is add a quick conditional code, showing an image instead of a text choice. I'll post my code.

```
<?php
if(get_field('our-rating') == "4 Stars")
{
echo '<img src="' . bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/4-stars.png">';
}
?>
```

My problem is that code is producing this HTML output:

```
www.site.com/wp-content/themes/dn4l<img src="/images/4-stars.png">
```

Am I doing something wrong? I could have sworn I've done this a dozen times before. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bloginfo` outputs, `get_bloginfo` returns. What's happening here is the `template_directory` is being output while you're building your string, but before you actually output your string.

Use `get_bloginfo` instead:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! I was rushing through thinking I knew everything and just typed off of memory, that'll teach me :)

Answer (score 0):

`bloginfo("template_directory")` is returning an empty string.

`www.site.com/wp-content/themes/dn4l` must be coming from somewhere else in your code.

Are you sure there aren't any echos being triggered? Try commenting out the echo line you present, you should just get `www.site.com/wp-content/themes/dn4l`.

Comment: When I comment out the echo, nothing gets displayed at all.